# Radio buttons returning null, trying to trigger css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to create a cube with css animations that rotates to a different face depending on the radio button checked. I checked online and found the example by Dave DeSandro for this, but my code won't work with the js, because I keep getting the error 'cannot read property 'querySelector' of null'. I kept the names of my radio buttons the same, but I'm not sure what's causing me to keep getting a null value.

```
    var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
    var radioGroup = document.querySelector('.radioButtons');
    var currentClass = '';

    function changeSide() {
      var checkedRadio = radioGroup.querySelector(':checked');
      var showClass = 'show-' + checkedRadio.value;
      if ( currentClass ) {
        cube.classList.remove( currentClass );
      }
      cube.classList.add( showClass );
      currentClass = showClass;
    }

    changeSide();

    radioGroup.addEventListener('change', changeSide);
```

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    perspective: 1500px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 80px;
  perspective: 400px;
}

.cube {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateZ(-100px);
    transition: transform 1s;
}

    .cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(   0deg); }
    .cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY( -90deg); }
    .cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-180deg); }
    .cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(  90deg); }
    .cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( -90deg); }
    .cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  90deg); }

.face {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.face-front{
    background-image: url('start.jpg');
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.face-back{
    background-image: url('mask.png');
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.face-left{
    background-image: url('gel.png');
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.face-top{
    background-image: url('glasses.png');
    transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.face-bottom{
    background-image: url('tp.png');
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.face-right{
    background-image: url('pen.png');
    transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
           <title>CUBE</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="cubeCode.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
          <script src="cubeCode.js"></script>
          <div class="main">
            <div class="cube">
              <div class="face  face-front"></div>
              <div class="face  face-back"></div>
              <div class="face  face-left"></div>
              <div class="face  face-top"></div>
              <div class="face  face-bottom"></div>
              <div class="face  face-right"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />    

   <p class="radioButtons">
        <input type="radio" name="rotate-face" value="front" checked />
        <label for="front">front</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rotate-face" value="back" />
        <label for="back">back</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rotate-face" value="left" />
        <label for="left">left</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rotate-face" value="top" />
        <label for="top">top</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rotate-face" value="bottom" />
        <label for="bottom">bottom</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rotate-face" value="right" />
        <label for="right">right</label>
    </p>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried replicating your error with code you provided and it all works for me when as soon as i create the div with .cube class -- could you provide code that makes up the cube?

Comment: yeah where is the cube in your HTML

Comment: @babis95 I have added the code to the post. Thanks

Comment: @nsCode I implemented the code again and there is no error - it works as intended.

Comment: Just from reading your code, it looks like your JS code is trying to access HTML elements, which haven't been created yet. Try to move your script tag to the end of body in your HTML.

Comment: @kriplerm i think thats the case also. You can also use defer to make your HTML load before script execute

Comment: @kriplerm Thanks, it works now!